# The binary file i made by compiler don't consists of just binary number why?

Tags: compiler-construction, operating-system, cpu-architecture

I have learned that the computer only works on zero and one in digital and logical design and a compiler is a program that converts source code to binary.
So just to conform that.I have wrote a simple c.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
printf("Hi am dan ");
}
```

After compiling that i have generated a binary file when i have opened it in the text editor there is not just 0,1 there is back slashes English words and too much this is what's inside. please can any body explain that.how computer can understand this all??

```
ELF\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00>\00\00\00\00@\00\00\00\00\00@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\A8\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00@\008\00\00@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00@\00@\00\00\00\00\00@\00@\00\00\00\00\00\C0\00\00\00\00\00\00\C0\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00@\00\00\00\00\00\00@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00@\00\00\00\00\00\DC\00\00\00\00\00\00\DC\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00 \00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\E0\00\00\00\00\00\00\E0`\00\00\00\00\00\E0`\00\00\00\00\000\00\00\00\00\00\008\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00 \00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\F8\00\00\00\00\00\00\F8`\00\00\00\00\00\F8`\00\00\00\00\00\D0\00\00\00\00\00\00\D0\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00@\00\00\00\00\00@\00\00\00\00\00D\00\00\00\00\00\00\00D\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00P\E5td\00\00\00\B0\00\00\00\00\00\00\B0@\00\00\00\00\00\B0@\00\00\00\00\004\00\00\00\00\00\00\004\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00Q\E5td\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00GNU\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00 \00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00GNU\00\F1\C6\E5Ed\C5UHX\BD\88\91WE\8A\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00$\00\00\00 \00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00libc.so.6\00printf\00__libc_start_main\00__gmon_start__\00GLIBC_2.2.5\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00ui  \00\00\003\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\C8`\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\E8`\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\F0`\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\F8`\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00H\83\ECH\8B \00H\85\C0t\E8C\00\00\00H\83\C4\C3\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\FF5 \00\FF% \00@\00\FF% \00h\00\00\00\00\E9\E0\FF\FF\FF\FF%\FA \00h\00\00\00\E9\D0\FF\FF\FF\FF%\F2 \00h\00\00\00\E9\C0\FF\FF\FF1\EDI\89\D1^H\89\E2H\83\E4\F0PTI\C7\C0\90@\00H\C7\C1 @\00H\C7\C7@\00\E8\B7\FF\FF\FF\F4fD\00\00\B8  `\00UH-    `\00H\83\F8H\89\E5v\B8\00\00\00\00H\85\C0t]\BF  `\00\FF\E0f\84\00\00\00\00\00]\C3fffff.\84\00\00\00\00\00\BE   `\00UH\81\EE   `\00H\C1\FEH\89\E5H\89\F0H\C1\E8?H\C6H\D1\FEt\B8\00\00\00\00H\85\C0t]\BF   `\00\FF\E0\00]\C3fD\00\00\80=I \00\00uUH\89\E5\E8n\FF\FF\FF]\C66 \00\F3\C3@\00\BF\F0`\00H\83?\00u\EB\93\00\B8\00\00\00\00H\85\C0t\F1UH\89\E5\FF\D0]\E9z\FF\FF\FFUH\89忤@\00\B8\00\00\00\00\E8\C7\FE\FF\FF]\C3D\00\00AWA\89\FFAVI\89\F6AUI\89\D5ATL\8D%\A8 \00UH\8D-\A8 \00SL)\E51\DBH\C1\FDH\83\EC\E8U\FE\FF\FFH\85\EDt\84\00\00\00\00\00L\89\EAL\89\F6D\89\FFA\FF\DCH\83\C3H9\EBu\EAH\83\C4[]A\A]A^A_\C3ff.\84\00\00\00\00\00\F3\C3\00\00H\83\ECH\83\C4\C3\00\00\00\00\00Hi am dan \00\00;4\00\00\00\00\00\00 \FE\FF\FF\80\00\00\00`\FE\FF\FFP\00\00\00V\FF\FF\FF\A8\00\00\00p\FF\FF\FF\C8\00\00\00\E0\FF\FF\FF\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00zR\00x\90\00\00\00\00\00\00\FE\FF\FF*\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00zR\00x\90\00\00$\00\00\00\00\00\00\98\FD\FF\FF@\00\00\00\00FJw\80\00?;*3$"\00\00\00\00\00\00\00D\00\00\00\A6\FE\FF\FF\00\00\00\00A\86C
P\00\00\00D\00\00\00d\00\00\00\A0\FE\FF\FFe\00\00\00\00B\8FE\8EE \8DE(\8CH0\86H8\83M@l8A0A(B BBB\00\00\00\00\AC\00\00\00\C8\FE\FF\FF\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\E0@\00\00\00\00\00\C0@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\A8@\00\00\00\00\00
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\94@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\E0`\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\E8`\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\F5\FE\FFo\00\00\00\00`@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\E0@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\80@\00\00\00\00\00
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00?\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\D0`\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00H\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00`@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00H@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00 \00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\FE\FF\FFo\00\00\00\00(@\00\00\00\00\00\FF\FF\FFo\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\F0\FF\FFo\00\00\00\00 @\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\F8`\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\E6@\00\00\00\00\00\F6@\00\00\00\00\00@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00GCC: (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2\00GCC: (Debian 4.8.4-1) 4.8.4\00\00.symtab\00.strtab\00.shstrtab\00.interp\00.note.ABI-tag\00.note.gnu.build-id\00.gnu.hash\00.dynsym\00.dynstr\00.gnu.version\00.gnu.version_r\00.rela.dyn\00.rela.plt\00.init\00.text\00.fini\00.rodata\00.eh_frame_hdr\00.eh_frame\00.init_array\00.fini_array\00.jcr\00.dynamic\00.got\00.got.plt\00.data\00.bss\00.comment\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00<@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00`@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\80@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\E0@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00 @\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00(@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00 \00H@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00
\00`@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\A8@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\D0@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00
\00@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\94@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\A0@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\B0@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\E8@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\E0`\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\E8`\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\F0`\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\F8`\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\C8`\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\D0`\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00    `\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00   `\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\F1\FF\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\F0`\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00
\00@@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00.\00\00\00\00
\00\80@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00A\00\00\00\00
\00\C0@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00W\00\00\00\00\00  `\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00f\00\00\00\00\00\E8`\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\8D\00\00\00\00
\00\E0@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\99\00\00\00\00\00\E0`\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\B8\00\00\00\00\F1\FF\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\F1\FF\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\BF\00\00\00\00\00\D8@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\CD\00\00\00\00\00\F0`\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\F1\FF\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\D9\00\00\00\00\00\00\E8`\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\EA\00\00\00\00\00\F8`\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\F3\00\00\00\00\00\00\E0`\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\D0`\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00
\00\90@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00,\00\00 \00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00H\00\00 \00\00\00  `\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00S\00\00\00\00   `\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00Z\00\00\00\00\94@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00`\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00t\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\93\00\00\00\00\00   `\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\A0\00\00 \00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\AF\00\00\00   `\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\BC\00\00\00\00\A0@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\CB\00\00\00
\00 @\00\00\00\00\00e\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\DB\00\00\00\00  `\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\E0\00\00\00
\00@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\E7\00\00\00\00    `\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\F3\00\00\00
\00@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\F8\00\00 \00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00  `\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00 \00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\002\00\00\00\00\A8@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00crtstuff.c\00__JCR_LIST__\00deregister_tm_clones\00register_tm_clones\00__do_global_dtors_aux\00completed.6661\00__do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry\00frame_dummy\00__frame_dummy_init_array_entry\00test.c\00__FRAME_END__\00__JCR_END__\00__init_array_end\00_DYNAMIC\00__init_array_start\00_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_\00__libc_csu_fini\00_ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable\00data_start\00_edata\00_fini\00printf@@GLIBC_2.2.5\00__libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.2.5\00__data_start\00__gmon_start__\00__dso_handle\00_IO_stdin_used\00__libc_csu_init\00_end\00_start\00__bss_start\00main\00_Jv_RegisterClasses\00__TMC_END__\00_ITM_registerTMCloneTable\00_init\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00 \00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\001\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00<@\00\00\00\00\00<\00\00\00\00\00\00$\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00D\00\00\00\F6\FF\FFo\00\00\00\00\00\00\00`@\00\00\00\00\00`\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00N\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\80@\00\00\00\00\00\80\00\00\00\00\00\00`\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00V\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\E0@\00\00\00\00\00\E0\00\00\00\00\00\00?\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00^\00\00\00\FF\FF\FFo\00\00\00\00\00\00\00 @\00\00\00\00\00 \00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00k\00\00\00\FE\FF\FFo\00\00\00\00\00\00\00(@\00\00\00\00\00(\00\00\00\00\00\00 \00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00z\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00H@\00\00\00\00\00H\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\84\00\00\00\00\00\00B\00\00\00\00\00\00\00`@\00\00\00\00\00`\00\00\00\00\00\00H\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\8E\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\A8@\00\00\00\00\00\A8\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\89\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\D0@\00\00\00\00\00\D0\00\00\00\00\00\00@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\94\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00@\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\82\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\9A\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\94@\00\00\00\00\00\94\00\00\00\00\00\00   \00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\A0\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\A0@\00\00\00\00\00\A0\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\A8\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\B0@\00\00\00\00\00\B0\00\00\00\00\00\004\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\B6\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\E8@\00\00\00\00\00\E8\00\00\00\00\00\00\F4\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\C0\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\E0`\00\00\00\00\00\E0\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\CC\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\E8`\00\00\00\00\00\E8\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\D8\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\F0`\00\00\00\00\00\F0\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\DD\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\F8`\00\00\00\00\00\F8\00\00\00\00\00\00\D0\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\E6\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\C8`\00\00\00\00\00\C8\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\EB\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\D0`\00\00\00\00\00\D0\00\00\00\00\00\000\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\F4\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00  `\00\00\00\00\00\00 \00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\FA\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00 `\00\00\00\00\00   \00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\FF\00\00\00\00\00\000\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00 \00\00\00\00\00\009\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00I   \00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00X
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00-\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00  \00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00p\00\00\00\00\00\008\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00
```

Comment: If you really care, start reading docs, then ask "why": [ELF format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format#Specifications)

Comment: What gave you the impression that this would compile to a binary file?

Comment: @user4419802 helped alot thanks

Comment: @Claies That's what i have been told by the teacher all these years.

Comment: @DannyRock `That's what i have been told by the teacher` Every teacher has to simplify the things. You may think "machine code" vs "executable file" similar to "working TV" vs "box in the store". Although the latter is "100% ready-to-use product", you still have to put the TV-set out of the box, plug some wires, and drop the packaging stuff out. So your question looks like: "why is my tv-set made of carton and paper?" It's not, it's just packaging.

Comment: @user4419802 actually i also didn't cared about all that before i was okay with that .. but now i m learning malware analysis and security so i feel like i should know every stuff..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expectation of what a binary file is, is wrong.

A binary file is not a text file containing numbers in binary format, it's a file that contains raw data in the native format of the computer.

The file contains just zeroes and ones, because that it what data ultimately is. You can't view the binary data as it is, because there is no way to display data in that form. Every kind of data that you see displayed is converted in some way or another so that it's in a form that humans can comprehend, for example as character shapes that we can read.

If you wanted to look at the data in binary representation, you would need a program that reads the data and converts each byte into the text representation of the number in binary notation.

The executeable file that you are looking at is program code in a specific format. The computer doesn't understand this, it needs an operating system that can read the file and put the data in the right place in memory so that it becomes runnable machine code.

Comment: thanks man by reading elf format and your answer now i got a lil concept so the os will read this and convert it in the assembly code and put it in the registers or some thing like that ??

Comment: @DannyRock: Yes, something like that. Strictly speaking, assembly code is not machine code, it's a programming language that has instructions that correspond directly to machine code. When you assemble an assembler program you get the machine code, for example in the form of an ELF file.